# Dealing with collections in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, associative-array

I have this table in which I want to register likes from users. The data type for likes is an array. `INT[]` I don't know if this is the best approach to handle like and unlike
I have not found an effective way to manipulate collection in order to toggle like/unlike from a user.

can we use sthg like an associative array in SQL? or, what would be the best approach with an array ? I could not find one example.
Thks for pointing me in the right direc†ion.

```
CREATE TABLE posts (
  pid SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INT REFERENCES users(uid),
  author VARCHAR REFERENCES users(username),
  title VARCHAR(255),
  content TEXT,
  date_created TIMESTAMP,
  like_user_id INT[] DEFAULT ARRAY[]::INT[],
  likes INT DEFAULT 0
);

const likePost = (req, res, next) => {
  const values = [req.body.id, req.body.user_id];
  console.log(values);
  const query = `UPDATE posts SET likes = likes - 1 WHERE pid = $1, UPDATE posts SET likes[1] = $2 WHERE pid = $1`;
  pool.query(query, values, (q_err, q_res) => {
    if (q_err) return next(q_err);
    res.json(`post ${req.body.id} succcessfully remove `);
  });
};
```

Comment: Arrays in general can be useful for list that don't get updated. The big issue with arrays is that they break the normal forms; in fact they break 1NF. If you want to "manage" lists of relationships with other entities, I would advise to get rid of arrays, and bring your database model to 3NF at least.